# Eclipse, Java project - How do I add a source folder where the folder name is part of the package name?

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I tried searching for the answer and got a lot of similar problems but not this exact issue.

I'm trying to set up Eclipse from a CVS project that has a non-Eclipse-friendly folder structure.

Inside the project folder, all the source code is under a folder named "com." Subsequently, all the import statements inside the source files are in form of:

```
import com.xxx.yyy.SomeObject;
```

Which, of course, refers to SomeObject.java located at com/xxx/yyy.

The problem is when I add the com folder inside Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source tab -> Add Folder, Eclipse complains about the import statement above. It says, "The declared package 'com.xxx.yyy' does not match the expected package 'xxx.yyy'".

How do I solve this?

Comment: technically if com is part of your package, then source would be com's parent folder. Unless you can do some symlink/shortcut magic, i think you need to move com into a "src" folder

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation, especially if your source files are all in one - or just a few - director(ies):

1) Check out your CVS project into a temp folder

2) Create a new Eclipse project from scratch.  It will create a "src" folder by default.

3) Create your package with Eclipse.  It will automatically create subfolders representing your package name (e.g. com.foo.mypackage).

4) Drag/drop your source into the Eclipse package

5) Make sure everything builds

6) Save the new Eclipse folder tree to CVS (ideally, use the CVS plugin for Eclipse to do this).

IMHO...

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for the suggestions. I have a bunch of packages that I'd need to manually create in step 3 so I'm afraid that's not viable. Is there any other way?